# PHP Google Analytics reporting API V4 Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I made a php script to get analytics report and locally on my Mac and on another virtualbox machine it works (I use service accounts system).
The script is the same as this google sample https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples
But when I move it to my production server I'm getting this error:
{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature." }

Can you help me?
What can cause this problem?